# how to call a PHP function using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i want to create login system in php using ajax here is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


// login function
 $('form#login').on('submit', function(){ 
    var url = document.getElementById('hidden').innerHTML;
    var login_result = $('.login_result');
    var input_data = $('form#login').serialize() + "&action=login";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: input_data,
        url: url + 'lib/my_func.php',
        success: function(responseText){ // Get the result and asign to each cases
            if(responseText == 0){
                login_result.html('<span class="error">Username or Password Incorrect!</span>');
            }
            else if(responseText == 1){
                window.location = 'userpage.php';
            }
            else{
                alert('Problem with sql query');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
 });




});
```

and here is my php function

```
function login()
{
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'login')
    {
        $user   =   $_POST['login'];
        $pas    =   $_POST['password'];

        echo $user;

    }
}
```

but in this php login function there in no output. and if i remove function echo $user is true, how to echo $user in login function
please help me

Comment: you have to call that function `login();`

Comment: yes i want to call login() function using ajax

Comment: Yes, just put `login();` under the end of the function so that it is actually is called to start your verification process.

Comment: i am not understand can you clear this please

Answer (score 1):

Use your js code as well but modify your my_func.php

```
<?php
   function login() {
     if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'login')
        {
            $user   =   $_POST['login'];
            $pas    =   $_POST['password'];

            echo $user;

        }
    }
    login();    
?>
```

UPD after creators comment:
You can specify which function to call in your ajax request by adding a special param(e.g. now you are using `&action=login`). The code of my_func.php is shown below:

```
<?php
       function login() {
         if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'login')
            {
                $user   =   $_POST['login'];
                $pas    =   $_POST['password'];

                echo $user;

            }
        }
        $action = $_GET['action'];
        if ($action == 'login') {
           login();
        } else {
           echo "No action {$action} found";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: but sir i want to use functions because in this file i create forget_password function etc.

Comment: @user1596202 You should make another request for forgot password. Or you may specify which func to call in your ajax request.

Comment: @user1596202 you are welcome. I've updated my answer, if solution is found, please marked question as resolved by accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
$('#submit').click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'your_url_of_php_file',
        data: "name="+$('#field_id').val()+"&email="+$('#field_id').val()+"",
        success:function(result)
        {
           alert(result)
        }
    })
}
```

and in php file

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['name']))
  {
      $name=$_POST['name'];
      $email=$_POST['email'];
      echo $email." ".$name;
  }
?>
```

Comment: sir i want to create this like WordPress, if in feature i use 5 or more different ajax request,then we will create septate file of each ajax request?

Comment: you want to call your php function from ajax?

Comment: @user1596202 Why do you wish to use a function? It seems that you are looking to run a functionality. This answer provides that.

Answer (score 0):

then you can use:

```
var input_data = $('form#login').serialize();
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'function.php',
  data:"function="+$('#function_name').val()+"&value="+input_data;
  success:function(result)
  {
     alert(result);
  }
})
```

in php:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['function']))
   {
     $_POST['function']($_POST['value']); 
   }

  function abc($data)
  {
     //some code
  }

?>
```

you just need to send function name and its values then in php your function will call auto...